# Error en formulario sql python tkinter

Tags: python, sql, tkinter

estoy empezando a programar, estoy queriendo hacer un programa para una empresa de transporte de encomiendas y quiero hacer un formulario para cargar boletas que cuando le de al botón de registrar este suba a la base de datos los datos del formulario, me encuentro con este problema les agradecería mucho si me dan una mano:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    sql= "INSERT INTO Boletas(num, fecha, nombre_o, localidad_o, telef_o, nombre_d, localidad_d, telef_d, metodp, descripcion, monto)\
            VALUES ('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}','{5}','{6}','{7}','{8}','{9}','{10}')".format(num.get(), fech.get(), nomo.get(), loco.get(), telo.get(), nomd.get(), locd.get(), teld.get(), mdp.get(), des.get(), mon.get())
    try:
        cursor.execute(sql)
        bd.commit()
        messagebox.showinfo(message="Registro exitoso", title="Aviso")
    except:
        bd.rollback()
        messagebox.showinfo(message="No registrado", title="Aviso")
```

Al rellenar todos los campos de mi formulario me sale la pestaña de Aviso "No Registrado" y si saco el Try y el Excep y le doy a registrar no pasa nada, no tira error ni carga al servidor los datos.

por las dudas dejo el codigo que use para crear la tabla en la db

`cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE Boletas (num VALCHAR(50), fecha VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, nombre_o VARCHAR(50), localidad_o VARCHAR(50), telef_o VARCHAR(10), nombre_d VARCHAR(50), localidad_d VARCHAR(50), telef_d VARCHAR(10), metododp VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, descripcion VARCHAR(50), monto VARCHAR(20))")`

Gracias!

Comment: Podrías colocar un código reproducible por favor? Algo que pueda copiar, pegar en mi editor, ejecutar, apretar el botón y que el fallo ocurra. Así será más facil encontrar el problema. Por favor mira [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Sacaste TODOS los try-except relacionados al boton? En tu programa tienes otra parte del código que capture errores silenciosamente y se llame cuando presionas el boton?